# Is there any other point about the questions not to ask on DA that should be added?

Tags: discussion, questions

The [FAQ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) actually lists the following points, about the questions that are not welcome here:

- Comparison between Drupal and other CMS's, blog software, or similar software
- Requests for tutorials, and other online resources
- Building a site from scratch
- Issues found in existing modules/themes
- Issues about drupal.org, or any of its sub-domains
- Recommendations for Drupal hosting

As far as I can see, this list is complete.

Is there anything that needs to be added? Did you see any questions that keep to be asked, and which are then successively closed because they aren't good questions for *Drupal Answers*?

Comment: How often does "replicate foo.com" in Drupal come up?

Comment: There are regularly (every month or two) questions that are basically "Write my code for me".  Perhaps it could be incorporated somehow that requests for pointers are welcome, but this is not a "freelancer forum"?

Comment: Adding [tag:featured] so that this hopefully gets more visibility.

Comment: @Chapabu There is a question tagged [meta-tag:faq] about what information should be provided when asking a question. Maybe an entry equivalent to "building a site from scratch" should be added.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, that's what I was getting at!  Sorry if I confused anyone :)

Comment: @MPD That could be considered part of "build a site from scratch" if the OP doesn't give any information about the already installed modules. It could also have a separate entry in the list, though.

Comment: @Chapabu There is no need to be sorry. I wanted to be sure the purpose of this question was clear. There are things that should be immediately clear in the FAQ page, and there are things that are reported in questions tagged [meta-tag:faq] here. This question is for a specific part of the FAQ page. Anyway, why don't you add that as answer? I will make the question Community Wiki in few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

There are regularly (every month or two) questions that are basically "Write my code for me". Perhaps it could be incorporated somehow that requests for pointers are welcome, but this is not a "freelancer forum"?

Comment: I can see that as "requests for writing code from scratch" with a note that questions showing the code being used, even if it doesn't work, are preferred.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yeah, something like that sounds good!  Code review = OK, code creation = not OK ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A variant of the "Building a site from scratch" questions are ones like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54836/which-theme-will-be-good-for-making-dating-website-like-match-com

I think these make need to be addressed, either by rewording as

- Building a site from scratch, or copying another site in Drupal

or as a sepate item

- Building a site from scratch
- Copying Drupal Answers, or any other site in Drupal

Comment: I think it is a necessary addition. I can imagine users saying "I am not asking how to build a website from scratch; I have a website." I can see it as "imitating an existing site" with a note that questions about how to implement specific functionality are fine. I think questions about imitating other sites are not fine, whatever the site is one build with Drupal, or not. [Continued]

Comment: Imagine that somebody would ask which modules to use to build a site like Drupal.org, and suppose that there isn't any indication of which modules Drupal.org uses. Users would try checking the HTML output produced from a page (hoping to find any indication), or they would guess which modules are used basing on the functionality that is exposed to the normal users. In both the cases, the question would not get answers, but guesses.

Comment: I added this as, "Implementing a functionality, or a layout, seen in a site for which only a screenshot is provided."